# Assigning integer value in a char array

Tags: c

I need a integer value to be stored in the char array.

```
int i; 
char example[5];

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    example[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Apparently this doesn't work.  How do I do this?

Comment: What value do you want to store in the array, the character `'0'` to `'4'`, or ASCII `0` to `4`, or something else?

Comment: the character '0' to '4' would do it.

Comment: are you trying to convert an int to a char array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
int i; 
char example[5];
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
example[i]=i+1+'0';
}
```

It will work for the single integer values 0 to 9. Need of `'0'` is in char array
it will store an ascii value. So we need to add the ascii value of zero to get the real integer value.

Or else as Iharob says, use the char array.

Comment: you should mention that '0' tp '9' are contiguous in ascii.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a too wide type to store it in a `char` so it would be good if you change the type of the counter

```
char i; 
char example[5];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    example[i] = i + 1;
}
```

You have to be aware that the `for` loop cannot have more than `CHAR_MAX` iterations.

If what yout want is to store the values to make `example` a string then you should add ascii `'0'` to make the values valid ascii characters, and you should add 1 extra `'\0'` character at the end of the array to make it a string

```
char i; 
char example[6];
for (i = 1 ; i < 6; i++) {
    example[i] = i + '0';
}
example[5] = '\0';
```

this will generate the string

```
12345
```

Comment: "int is a too wide type to store it in a char so you just need to change the type of the counter"  But he is only using numbers that fit in a char, so that doesn't matter...  Also your code is completely wrong. `example ['1']` will crash and burn.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
example[i]=i+1+'0';
```

and

```
char example[5] //no terminator here
char example[5]; 
               ^^^
```